# How can I check that I added admob Ads to unity game correctly?

Tags: unity-game-engine, admob

I Added banner ad to my unity game by importing google admob package then write banner ad script.
When I tested the game in the Unity editor it get me a banner ad but without an admob logo just it says "This is a test  SmartBanner".
But when I Built The game And published it on google play store and play it I cant see any ads!!.
So is there any way to check if i added ads correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest taking a look at admob's documentation about test ads here -> https://developers.google.com/admob/android/test-ads

Basically if you can see a test ad for every type then you are good to go. There are other reasons for live ads to not show up depending on the users country and internet usage and etc... ads can return as `no-fill` meaning ad network couldn't fill the ad request.

If you also take a log at your device logs at runtime you should see logs about admob rather if it is initialized correctly or missing something. Like i said you should read and follow the documentation carefully.